# Fixed it. What is the option_description used for in the build_dict function in the dataMeta package in R?

Tags: r, metadata, data-science, data-analysis

I have a dataset with some 100,000 tweets and their sentiment scores attached. The original dataset just has two columns one for the tweets and one for their sentiment scores.

I am trying to build a data dictionary for it using the dataMeta package. Here is the code that I have writtern so far:

```
#Data Dictionary
var_desc<-c("Sentiment Score 0 for Negative sentences and 4 for Positive sentences","The tweets collected")
var_type<-c(0,1)

#Creating the Linker Data Frame
linker <- build_linker(tweets_train, variable_description = var_desc, variable_type = var_type)
linker

#Build the data dictionary
dict<-build_dict(my.data = tweets_train,linker=linker,option_description = NULL, prompt_varopts = F)
kable(dict,format="html",caption="Data dictionary for the Training dataset")
```

My problem is in the data dictionary I have provided the Variable Name and the Variable Description but I think in the Variable Options column it is trying to print the entire 100,000 tweets which I want to avoid. Is it possible for me to set that column up too manually. Would the option_description in the build_dict function be of any help to do it?
I tried getting some idea about it from online but to no use. Here is the link that I have followed till now:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dataMeta/vignettes/dataMeta_Vignette.html

This is the first time I am trying to build a data dictionary and hence the struggle. Any suggestions would be extremely appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Had initially set: var_type<-c(0,1). Changed it to var_type<-c(0,0) and was able to get the desired result.